# How to disable or hide the scope buttons in searchbar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am new to ios I am using Xcode 7 and swift 2 I have implemented a searchbar controler with my `tableViewController` like this:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
definesPresentationContext = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

// Setup the Scope Bar
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Chocolate"]
searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Default
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

But I don't want the scope buttons in this case. How can I hide them?

Note, this is not working for me:

```
searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false
```

Comment: scopeButtonTitles make to nil like this searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = nil

Comment: thanks that worked !

Comment: @Vinodh answer updated, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Storyboard**

Using Search Display Controller via storyboard, go to the search bar attributes inspector and uncheck the "Shows Scope Bar" if it is checked.and remove the scope titles if any.

**Programmatically**

Using Search Display Controller programmatically then you have to remove this part, will not show the scope bar

```
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Chocolate"]
searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false
```

Or

Make the scopeButtonTitles to **nil** will also remove the buttons in scope bar

```
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = nil
```